# Border around each letter in a textview

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I make a black border around each letter in a textview ?
I've tried:

```
tvText.setText(android.text.Html.fromHtml("<span style=\"border:1px solid #000000\">bla</span>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a custom typeface? Check here if there is one with a border:
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/50/50
You can then do like this:

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"BLOODY.ttf");
textView.setTypeface(font);
```